# Samba - user auth against AD and local passdb

Tags: active-directory, authentication, samba

I have only a short question.
Is it possible to set up a samba server, who's able to authenticate some users against Active Directory and some users against a local passdb file?

We want to exchange (large) files between company users and our customer. So I cant add the customer users into our AD - the win Admins don't want it. So at the moment I have a separate account db. The company users exists in AD and separately with additional accounts on my linux samba box

Now it would be nice, if i can get the company users via AD and then I'll add the customer (by hand) to a local passdb.

Thanks for you help
peter

Answer (score 3):

This is possible (perhaps in more recent versions of samba):

If you are using `security = ads` in your `smb.conf` file, to be part of a domain, you can still add users locally (using useradd) and then use `smbpasswd -a username` to add a password for them (to the default tdb backend, as I hadn't configured this explicitly).

You'll need to use `SERVERNAME\username` as the name to connect as, rather than `DOMAIN\username`, but otherwise this appears to work just fine.

This worked for me on CentOS 7 with samba 4.2.3 with a Windows 7 (domain-joined) client, but I cannot vouch for any other versions.

*Note: You'll still need the user to be added to the local passwd file (or another user information source which is in use via NSS, such as LDAP or NIS) so that `getent passwd username` works, but they don't need to have a valid shell or a system password for samba to work OK.*

Answer (score 0):

If you got two ips, you can run two instances of samba one that authenticates against ad and one against the local db. see http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Multiple_Server_Instances, i do not think it is possible to mix authentication methods on one samba host.

Comment: It is possible - see my answer.  It seems that samba will use the local password database, but only when you explicitly specify the domain as the name of the server.